# Memcached - Saving Custom Array

Tags: caching

I have the memcache module installed on Drupal 7. While it works fine I would like to implement some custom caching in some of my modules. For example, if I want to store the array:

```
$data = array('hi'=>1,'bye'=>2);
```

I can normally do the following:

```
$memcache_obj = memcache_connect('memcache_host', 11211);
memcache_set($memcache_obj, 'var_key', $data, 0, 30);
```

How can I do the equivalent in Drupal using the memcache module. I am trying to avoid having to declare the $memcache_obj each time and just use the one designated by the module.

Answer (score 2):

With Drupal you are not supposed to manage the cache backend by yourself. Once memcached is set as your cache backend, you can just use the cache functions [cache_set](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21cache.inc/function/cache_set/7)(), [cache_get](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21cache.inc/function/cache_get/7)(), etc. and this data will go to cache.